# Searching in every contact field in iPhone

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, contacts

I am looking for an app that is able to search a string in every fields of my contacts on the iPhone (same as in outlook).

Comment: In Address Book contacts ???

Comment: Do you just want to search a contact on your iPhone ? You are aware that if you scroll to the left in Springboard (the "app overview") you'll end up in a search window which among other things, also searches your contacts ?

Comment: iphone search find only the name and nothing else.

Comment: yet for another app that should be just a built in feature...

Answer (score 1):

Try [Contact Find](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contact-find/id290153951?mt=8) by Piet Jonas in the App Store or [Fast Contacts](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/fast-contacts/id286543435?mt=8) by SpiceLoop also on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FindNDialEG.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/findndialeg/id438741268?mt=8)

It says it can search any string.

Comment: That app hasn't gotten a single review and no stars. Has anyone actually used it?